# Firebase cloud functions CAN'T find static files in public folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

- project

  - stripejs

    - functions

      - index.js
      - public

        - success.html

It's been hours I'm trying to redirect an API ( using cloud functions) to my html page (inside the public folder).

```
router.get('/finishOnboarding',  async (req,res) => {

    let content =  path.resolve('../public/success.html')
    res.sendFile(content);

});
```

I tried multiples things.

1. put the public folder Outside of the functions folder, then i noticed i need to nest it inside because when deploying it need to be accessed in google cloud
2. using `__dirname` + absolute path

No matters what I do, When I'm checking the Functions logs I always got the same error :

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/public/success.html'
```

If I'm trying to redirect using

```
path.join(__dirname, '/public/success.html');
```

I got :

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/workspace/routes/public/success.html'
```

firebase.json is configured as needed

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "functions/public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "function": "app"
      }
    ]  
  },
  "emulators": {
    "hosting": {
      "port": 5003
    }
  }
}
```

Where is the problem coming from? I'm sure its a simple problem with the paths, but Im very confused..

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Functions and Hosting run on completely separate infrastructure, so you can't reach from one to the other with a `path` type call.

If you want to **redirect** the user, you'll need to send a redirect instruction on the response. Doing that means the browser will get the instruction to request a different URL, and that request will then be served by Firebase Hosting.

If you want to **rewrite** the response (so serve HTML from a different location within your code), you will need to have those files *inside* (or under) the `functions` folder:

- project

  - stripejs

    - functions

      - index.js
      - public

        - success.html

Comment: This is exactly what I got sir, the public folder is inside the functions folder

Comment: hmm.. so it's better to get the ``public`` folder out, and just make another request  tu redirect to the Firebase Hosting url ?

Comment: Neither is *better*, it just depends on what you want to do. If you want the HTML to be served by Firebase Hosting, send a redirect instruction back to the caller (e.g. with `res.redirect(...)`).